# How do I change frontend folder location and configure it in Vaadin14?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

How do I change the default frontend folder location in a maven Vaadin 14 project from `${project.basedir}/frontend` to `${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend`?

Also, Vaadin plugin outputs frontend folder in maven build output directory instead of the war exploded directory, where I would expect it to be.

How do it make it to work since I did not map this folder into my web.xml file?

How do I make it put frontend folder into the war archive and see which configuration it is using to make the compiled front end visible to my application?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to change that.

Comment: Because it messes up my project organization. Because it should be simple but, as it seems, it is not. I also don't understand how I could deploy my war exploded application and it find that folder without any specification whatsoever.

Comment: But you don't have to change anything. The Vaadin plugin does everything for you and deployment works fine

Comment: Yes I have, I am not dealing with a new application so, no, de deployment don't go as smoothly as in a green field project, and leaving frontend in root will mess with its organization. I also figured it would break multi modules projects as well, so I thinks it is better to put it on src/main, where source code should be in a maven project, and leave the configuration explicit to avoid future problems. I, however, don't understand how knowing my motivations help you answer my question.

Comment: Anyway, I already figured out how to change the folder location properly, I didn't understand what the plugin was doing and how Vaadin deal with frontend folder both in dev and prod mode, and there is no documentation for the plugin, so it took some time to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vaadin uses the frontend folder differently in both dev and production modes. In production it builds the frontend using the `build-frontend` goal. Vaadin Maven Plugin don't have a proper documentation, the best place I found explaining what each goals do is here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-advanced.html. This page explains that `build-frontend` is responsible for building and putting the frontend processed into WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\VAADIN\build when in production mode.

Dev mode is very different, development instructions explains that if you don't use an embedded server you should configure your IDE to run `prepare-frontend` goal before deployment: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/workflow/run-on-server-intellij.html. But `prepare-frontend` just creates the empty frontend folder into target, how does it find frontend files if the folder is empty and nothing is copied to the war exploded folder? Answer: when you run the application, Vaadin has a DevModeInitializer that creates the file `generated-flow-imports.js` into target/frontend, which refer directly to the project source files, so that any modifications made at them may be reflected immediately, and that's why there is no need of any configuration in web.xml or context listener.

Dev mode make kind of a hack with frontend folder to make development smoother, and prod mode compile everything from frontend into a minified file served by the Vaadin servlet, so only in prod mode frontend goes into the war file. In the first case, `prepare-frontend` must be used, in the second, `build-frontend` must be used also. So, in order to modify the frontend folder location, one must change the plugin configuration in those two goals:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <frontendDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontendDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <frontendDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontendDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

That way, the modification will work in both dev and production mode.

Comment: could you update the links?

Comment: They were links for vaadin docs, if they moved it I am not sure where they should be or if the new docs reflect the solution proposed here.