# How use another folder for webapp (Vaadin 23) in production mode

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

I have vaadin application (version vaadin 23.2.7 and java 11). I have problem, I need use tiles (map OSM) for my application and this files need in another folder(not WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\VAADIN) for web content.

But docs defines a different directory for web content (WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\VAADIN), which is located **in the jar archive**:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/production/production-build
and
[How do I change frontend folder location and configure it in Vaadin14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479784/how-do-i-change-frontend-folder-location-and-configure-it-in-vaadin14)

I use leaflet with Vaadin, therefore the tile files must be located in the web directory (otherwise leaflet.js will not have access to the files);

As a result, my jar archive has a large size, as it includes all tiles.

Please help me, how can I use another directory (I want to store tiles in a directory, not in a JAR archive in WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\VAADIN)?  The solution above did not help

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/553cf24a-aade-4a91-a94d-9f2293333d44 -->
    <groupId>oniip.tetra.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>tetraweb</artifactId>
    <name>tetraweb</name>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.2.7</vaadin.version>
        <!-- this parameter is needed as spring-boot bom overwrites it -->
        <selenium.version>4.5.3</selenium.version>
        <!-- selenium is so much verbose -->
        <maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile>true</maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.appreciated/apexcharts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.appreciated</groupId>
            <artifactId>apexcharts</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.bbottema</groupId>
            <artifactId>emailaddress-rfc2822</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/layout -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/html2pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Нумерация таблицы GRID-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.klaudeta</groupId>
            <artifactId>grid-pagination</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Create Excel-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Локальные репозитории -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jlibrtp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibrtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
<!--            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibrtp.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
<!--            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/snmp4j-1.11.3.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tetra.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>tetraCommons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    <!--        <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/TetraCommons-1.0.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tetramap</groupId>
            <artifactId>tetraMap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
<!--            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/tetraMap-1.0.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>inst_1</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>org.jlibrtp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jlibrtp</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/jlibrtp.jar</file>
                            <localRepositoryPath>/home/oniip/.m2/repository</localRepositoryPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>inst_2</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>org.snmp4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>snmp4j</artifactId>
                            <version>1.11.3</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/snmp4j-1.11.3.jar</file>
                            <localRepositoryPath>/home/oniip/.m2/repository</localRepositoryPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>inst_3</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>tetra.commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tetraCommons</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/TetraCommons-1.0.jar</file>
                            <localRepositoryPath>/home/oniip/.m2/repository</localRepositoryPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>inst_4</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>tetramap</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tetraMap</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/tetraMap-1.0.jar</file>
                            <localRepositoryPath>/home/oniip/.m2/repository</localRepositoryPath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5037</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <frontendDirectory>${project.basedir}/frontend</frontendDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Исключаем модуль Development Server -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev-server</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <frontendDirectory>${project.basedir}/frontend</frontendDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I found a answer, but it isn't work :(

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST_VERSION</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraJars>
            <jar>META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/</jar>
        </extraJars>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

extraJars - Element extraJars is not allowed here

or

```
                <configuration>
                    <resourcesDirectory>path/to/custom/webapp</resourcesDirectory>
                </configuration>
```

resourcesDirectory - Element resourcesDirectory is not allowed here

Comment: Just make sure I understand your question. You want to load the tiles from an external folder when running the app?

Comment: Yes. I don't save tiles in jar file (WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\VAADIN). I want save tiles in external webapp folder, example "frontend"

Comment: But then you don't need to change the frontend folder location. Just load the tiles from the external folder. It would be best if you make the path configurable

Comment: I use leaflet with java. Leaflet (javascript) is located in a web container. Leaflet does not have access to other directories except META-INF\VAADIN\webapp :(And it is leaflet that loads the map tiles. I can't use java to set up a path for it outside the web container :( I was hoping that I could move META-INF\VAADIN\webapp from the jar file to another location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to move the web container to another location, but it didn't work out. https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/production/production-build . I wrote to the official Vaadin website, I did not receive a response.

I used the leaflet javascript library. This library had access only to the web container or http (smb, file did not work).

I have created a controller.

```
@RestController
public class TileController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TileController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/maps", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getTile(@RequestParam String schema, int z, int x, int y, String extension) throws IOException {
        String urlTile = "maps/" + schema + "/" + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + extension;
        logger.info("Загружается тайл " + urlTile);
        File file = new File(urlTile);
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }

}
```

I was able to do without changing the path of the web container /META-INF/VAADIN/webapp/. My problem was that the web container was inside the jar file and I couldn't move it. Therefore, I had to place several gigabytes of data in a jar file. I solved this problem using the http controller